# Derivative of $\rm a^T X^T X X^T X b$ with respect to $\rm X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I'm trying to take the derivative of a 4th order equation with respect to a matrix. It has the following form

$$\frac{\displaystyle \partial \bf a^T X^T X X^T X b}{\displaystyle \partial \bf X} = \Large ?$$

$\bf a$ and $\bf b$ are vectors and $\bf X$ is a matrix so, in effect, it's the derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix.

I found the basic derivatives in [Matrix Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) on Wikipedia and I found the second order derivative in [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). This gives me the solution for the second order case

$$\frac{\displaystyle \partial \bf a^T X^T X b}{\displaystyle \partial \bf X} = \bf X (ab^T+ba^T)$$

I wonder if there is a similar solution for the 4th order case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience, define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
 M &= X^TX = M^T \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and this new variable. Now finding the differential and gradient is straighforward.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= ab^T:MM^T \cr\cr
df &= ab^T:(dM\,M^T+M\,dM^T) \cr
   &= ab^T:2\,{\rm sym}(dM\,M^T) \cr
  &= 2\,{\rm sym}(ab^T):dM\,M^T \cr
  &= (ab^T+ba^T):dM\,M^T \cr
  &= (ab^T+ba^T)M:dM \cr
  &= (ab^T+ba^T)M:2\,{\rm sym}(X^TdX) \cr
  &= \Big(M(ab^T+ba^T)+(ab^T+ba^T)M\Big):X^TdX \cr
  &= \Big(XM(ab^T+ba^T)+X(ab^T+ba^T)M\Big):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= XM(ab^T+ba^T)+X(ab^T+ba^T)M\cr
  &= XX^TX(ab^T+ba^T)+X(ab^T+ba^T)X^TX\cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Hi, what does sym mean here? Thanks.

Comment: @Integrals It is a function used to decompose a matrix into the sum of its symmetric and skew parts $$\eqalign{\operatorname{sym}(A)&=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)\cr \operatorname{skew}(A)&=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)\cr A&=\operatorname{sym}(A)+\operatorname{skew}(A)\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm X) = \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b$$

The directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\mathrm V$ at $\mathrm X$ is

$$\begin{array}{rl} D_{\mathrm V} f (\mathrm X) &= \mathrm a^T \mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b + \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm V \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b + \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm b + \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm V \mathrm b\\ &= \mbox{tr} (\mathrm a^T \mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm V \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm b) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm V \mathrm b)\\ &= \mbox{tr} (\mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm V) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm V^T \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X) + \mbox{tr} (\mathrm b \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm V)\\ &= \langle \mathrm V, \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T \rangle + \langle \mathrm X \mathrm a \mathrm b^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X, \mathrm V \rangle + \langle \mathrm V, \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \rangle + \langle \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm a \mathrm b^T, \mathrm V \rangle\end{array}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{array}{rl} \nabla_{\mathrm x} f (\mathrm X) &= \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T + \mathrm X \mathrm a \mathrm b^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X + \mathrm X \mathrm b \mathrm a^T \mathrm X^T \mathrm X + \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \mathrm a \mathrm b^T\\ &= \mathrm X \mathrm X^T \mathrm X (\mathrm a \mathrm b^T + \mathrm b \mathrm a^T) + \mathrm X (\mathrm a \mathrm b^T + \mathrm b \mathrm a^T) \mathrm X^T \mathrm X \end{array}$$

Comment: Can you please share some resource to help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: @learner Search for "directional derivative" and "Frobenius inner product". Note how the directional derivative is the inner product of the gradient and the direction vector. The rest should follow.